# software architecture for php

Tags: php, social-networking

My friend said "php is not organized, so, the software architecture is bad with this language"

i need to build a social networking, with php... is it possible to do the software architecture of a simple way with php?

and... Object-Oriented PHP is more easy than Structured-PHP for to do the architecture?

Comment: and there I was thinking bad software architecture is mainly the result of bad architects.

Answer (score 3):

PHP will work JUST fine for your social networking site.  It might be worth your time looking into some of the frameworks like CakePHP, ZendFramework...etc though if you're worried about organization/structure.  But overall, PHP will more than meet your needs.

Answer (score 1):

PHP is a tool.  Like any tool, it has things that it is better at than others.  Like any tool, it can be misused.

When choosing the tool you will use, you first must understand the problem you are trying to address.

Look at all the things that you think you will be doing with your application.  Scalability, performance, maintainability, including finding/training those who will maintain the application in the long haul.

Then pick the appropriate tool for the job based on your knowledge of the ground work.

PHP is not C++, or C#, or Erlang, or whatever.  PHP is PHP and is very good at what PHP does.

Answer (score 0):

If I may suggest, your question hints to me that you not be programming it in the first place and that you should look into setting up/customizing an open source implementations of whatever you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook is done in PHP, so yes, its suited for your project

Comment: Face what?  I'm sure he's talking about a large-scale project, so please use examples to fit accordingly.  ;)